# New option in closing a Stack Overflow question

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

**Edit**

I'm seeing a lot of people saying there won't be new close messages and I get the message.

I'm wondering why is there a push to provide users with less specific information?

Does not basic usability imply the more information we give the users the better their experience of SO will be?

**Prior**

Right now we have a number of options to close questions but I feel there is one missing.

I will often see questions which are a statement of a problem that are basically a request to code a solution as op. to a problem a user is having.

My feeling is if you can look at the question and know the answer is "Hire a programmer".  Such questions should be closed.  I'm not sure what the exact wording on the reason should be but I feel like this is an option which is left out of the close choices.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I think the widespread consensus is to close "please do it for me" questions as `not a real question`.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: I agree this is the best option right now, but I wonder about the user who asks these questions, is this answer really going to put them on the right track -- I don't think so.

Comment: @Hogan true. For the moment, I would say leaving a comment explaining the situation is the best one can do. For new users, I think that is a good idea anyway.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that those "new users" will really be future SO users in the first place, so it doesn't really matter whether or not they understand the close reason. It seems to me that most people looking for a quick answer for their work just hit as many "boards" as they can with the same question, then go on to the next problem, so explaining _why_ something was closed isn't useful to them.

Comment: @Michael I agree with you in general, but there are notable exceptions where inability to express themselves in english and / or lack of technical ability initially *look* like `plz-send-teh-codez` but there is willingness to learn and show some effort. I'm usually for giving newcomers the benefit of the doubt - but true, there are cases that are clearly not worth even that.

Comment: You're probably right. Just cynicism rearing its ugly head.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be new close reasons, they tend to go the other way around (merging into less)

**Too localized** may be a good choice for something like that.

> This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is **not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.**

Comment: Too localized??  Really?  Wow that makes no sense to me.

Comment: @hog, did you read the bold part?

Comment: sure I did.  Implementing a standard linked-list HW assignment for Programming 1 applicable to everyone who takes Programming 1 is but would still be an example of the type of question I'm describing.